# How does the standard define the capture of runtime-bound array?

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc, clang, c++17

Please consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    volatile auto width = uint64_t(5);

    alignas(16)
    char runtime[width]; std::iota(runtime,runtime+width,'1');

    auto out = [](auto& curr) { std::cout << curr; };

    auto capt_ref_to_runtime_bound_arr = [&runtime,width,out](auto &curr) { 
                                             std::for_each(runtime, runtime+width, out); 
                                             std::cout << " and width=" 
                                                       << sizeof(runtime) / sizeof(*runtime)
                                                       << '\n'; 
                                         };

    // clang code crashes even if below is commented out.
    // std::for_each(runtime,runtime+width,capt_ref_to_runtime_bound_arr);
}
```

about the `[&runtime]` capture

1. GCC seems to decay `int(&)[width]` to `char *` (see wandbox below)
2. clang just crashes into a red text chunk (see wandbox below)

Later, I ran to [N3639](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3639.html), it says some features are cut off (e.g. sizeof in the demo above is actually ill-form). But why don't compilers explain these cut offs to me? And if the standard allow this kind of capture, how does they define it?

---

ASM: [godbolt.org/g/ptRRRp](https://godbolt.org/g/ptRRRp)

GCC 7.2 -O1: [wandbox.org/permlink/30muSDtbxZYeGV2p](https://wandbox.org/permlink/30muSDtbxZYeGV2p)

clang 5.0 -O1: [wandbox.org/permlink/yvvRhBLFXzzxmihi](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yvvRhBLFXzzxmihi)

Comment: The standard doesn't allow variable length arrays.

Comment: *why don't compilers explain these cut offs to me* Use `-std=c++?? -Wall -pedantic`. Do **not** use -std=gnuxxxx if you want standard compliance.

Comment: clang crash is new for v5. It may or may not be related to the issue. It's simply a compiler bug. There's no crash in prior versions.

Answer (score 11):

**C++ standard ([Bjarne Stroustrup](https://is.muni.cz/www/408176/38744863/The_C__Programming_Language__Stroustrup_.pdf)) :**

> The number of elements of the array, the array bound, **must be a
>   constant expression** (§C.5). If you need variable bounds, use a
>   vector(§3.7.1, §16.3). For example:
>
> ```
> void f(int i)
> {
>   int v1[i] ; / / error: array size not a constant expression
>   vector<int> v2(i) ; / / ok
> }
> ```

So, In all current and past C++ standards, that code is ill-formed. [Variable Length Arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are a C99 feature not a C++ feature.

Comment: runtime-bound array is considered as ill-form or undefined behavior or implementation defined?

Comment: @sandthorn "*must be a constant expression*" So the code is ill-formed if it is not.

Comment: @sandthorn it is considered ill-formed program. It should not compile. Compilers, which allows that, do it as a non-standard extention and, technically speaking, you are not using C++ anymore. Those extentions need not to follow common C++ conventions, or interact nicely with other C++ features. You need to consult compiler extention documentation.

Comment: If anyone knows the current status of N3639, let me know please.

Comment: @sandthorn - It was never made part of any standard release. Current proposal can be found here http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0785r0.html

Comment: @BoPersson Interesting. I don't know which design will slit VLA into the standard and make it legit finally. But I'm sure Bjarne's one needs a good rename!

Comment: It is an ill-formed program. The language definition requires that the compiler **issue a diagnostic**. It does not require that the code not compile. Having issued a diagnostic, the compiler is free to do whatever the implementor wants. That’s the hook for implementation-specific extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Variable-length arrays in C++ are a GNU extension. There used to be some plans to add them to the language (in a more restricted fashion than the GNU extension).  One of the challenges is that the C++ type system assumes that types have constant size and are fully laid out at compile time (otherwise, template metaprogramming would not work as it does today).

In previous GCC versions, it was sometimes possible to use variably modified types in templates, but this should have been fixed.

Comment: This means that N3639 isn't fully approved yet, is it? How is N3639 doing now? Off the table already?

Answer (score 1):

[Owner of question]

It looks like N3639 was moved to Array Extensions TS [N3830](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3820.html) and then Array TS was [widthdrawn](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental) on 2013-10-10.

VLAs have not won among the community yet.

[cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental)

[open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3820.html](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3820.html)